# Download multiple images from Firebase Storage

Tags: javascript, php, firebase, firebase-storage

I am giving my first steps with Firebase Storage Web and confess that Javascript is not my speciality either.

I have a web page (PHP) with a list of people names and I want to show their repective photo next to the name. The images are saved in a Firebase Storage folder.

Here is a simple example of the html (generated with PHP):

```
<div id="people_list">
    <div class="list_row">
        <div class="photo">
            <img id="photo1" src="images/stdphoto.png" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            People Name 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="list_row">
        <div class="photo">
            <img id="photo2" src="images/stdphoto.png" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            People Name 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already added the Firebase API following the instructions in this page https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup and initialize it like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously(); // Ignoring security for now
```

And here is my code to load ONE photo. It works perfectly!

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var refPath = storage.ref('photos/johnnydepp.jpg');
refPath.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    document.getElementById('photo1').src = url;
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

But now I am trying to load all the images in the page, so I created an Javascript array variable with the file names (loaded with PHP) an did like this:

```
var photos = ["johnnydepp", "jimcarrey", "emmawatson"];

var photoId = 0;
var refPath = null;
var storage = firebase.storage();
for (var i = 0; i <= photos.length - 1; i++) {
    photoId = i + 1;
    refPath = storage.ref('photos/' + photos[i] + '.jpg');
    refPath.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        document.getElementById('photo' + photoId).src = url;
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

I do not know why, but only the last photo in the list is being loaded. There are no errors in the Javascript console.

Please, do you know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT (my solution):**

```
const promises = [];

photos.forEach(val => {
    const promise = firebase.storage()
        .ref('photos/' + val + '.jpg')
        .getDownloadURL()
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error', err);
            return "";
        })
        .then(fileUrl => {
            return fileUrl;
        });
    promises.push(promise);
});

Promise.all(promises)
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error', err);
    })
    .then(urls => {
        for (var i = 0; i <= urls.length - 1; i++) {
            if (urls[i] != '') {
                document.getElementById('photo' + (i + 1)).src = urls[i];
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Guybrush Threepwood!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using an async function inside a loop, you should use a self-wrapping function this way:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= photos.length - 1; i++) {
    photoId = i + 1;
    refPath = storage.ref('photos/' + photos[i] + '.jpg');
    (function(pid) {
        refPath.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            document.getElementById('photo' + pid).src = url;
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    })(photoId);
}
```

Your code doesn't work because you receive the value from firebase after a delay, when you call `getElemById(photoId)`, `photoId`'s value is already changed. You can see the same behaviour here:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= photos.length - 1; i++) {
    photoId = i + 1;
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(photoId);
    }, 1000)
}
```

A self-wrapping function creates a [closure](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) that keeps your `photoId` value

Comment: Thank you Devid! Your explanation was very good, I understood what I was doing wrong. I will accept your answer, but also leave my solution in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The fetching download url are async requests (promises) and you execute the next loop cycle without letting the previous ones to finish and thus only last one is executed completely.

I suggest you take a different approach.

```
var photos = ["johnnydepp", "jimcarrey", "emmawatson"];

var photoId = 0;
var storage = firebase.storage();
var promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= photos.length - 1; i++) {
    photoId = i + 1;
    promises.push(storage.ref('photos/' + photos[i] + '.jpg').getDownloadURL());
}

photoId = 0;
Promise.all(promises, data => {
    for (var i = 0; i <= photos.length - 1; i++) {
        photoId = i + 1;
        document.getElementById('photo' + photoId).src = data[i];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you Anand, but are you sure this work? I can't make it to work, even when removing the loops and use static values...